# Column & row names for matrix values greater than the column mean of their corresponding columns

Tags: r, matrix

I am looking for a way to get the column and row names for values in the matrix in which the value is `>=` the mean of the column which it is in. I am new to R matrices.

```
m <- matrix(c(1:20), rnow=4)
colnames(m) <- c("A1","A2", "B1", "B2")
rownames(m) <- c("Y1","Y2", "Z1", "Z2", "Z3")

> m
      A1 A2 B1 B2
   Y1  1  6 11 16
   Y2  2  7 12 17
   Z1  3  8 13 18
   Z2  4  9 14 19
   Z3  5 10 15 20
```

The means are given below.

```
> colMeans(dummy_expr)
   A1 A2 B1 B2 
   3  8 13 18
```

I want to get the following:

```
row col
Z1  A1
Z2  A1
Z3  A1
Z1  A2
Z2  A2
Z3  A2
Z1  B1
Z2  B1
Z3  B1
Z1  B2
Z2  B2
Z3  B2
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
apply(m, 1:2, function(x) x>=colMeans(m))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine which elements of `m` are no smaller than the column means with `which` using `arr.ind=TRUE`, and then you can convert these indices to the row and column names using standard indexing into `rownames(m)` and `colnames(m)`.

```
indices <- which(t(t(m) >= colMeans(m)), arr.ind=TRUE)
indices[,"row"] <- rownames(m)[as.numeric(indices[,"row"])]
indices[,"col"] <- colnames(m)[as.numeric(indices[,"col"])]
indices
#    row  col 
# Z1 "Z1" "A1"
# Z2 "Z2" "A1"
# Z3 "Z3" "A1"
# Z1 "Z1" "A2"
# Z2 "Z2" "A2"
# Z3 "Z3" "A2"
# Z1 "Z1" "B1"
# Z2 "Z2" "B1"
# Z3 "Z3" "B1"
# Z1 "Z1" "B2"
# Z2 "Z2" "B2"
# Z3 "Z3" "B2"
```

The most involved command was the first one, so I'll walk through it in pieces.

- `t(m)` takes the transpose of the `m` matrix.

```
t(m)
#    Y1 Y2 Z1 Z2 Z3
# A1  1  2  3  4  5
# A2  6  7  8  9 10
# B1 11 12 13 14 15
# B2 16 17 18 19 20
```

- `t(m) >= colMeans(m)` returns whether the element in each row of `t(m)` is no smaller than the corresponding element in `colMeans(m)`; since we transposed `m` this result is the transposed version of the logical matrix indicating whether each element in `m` is no smaller than its associated column mean.

```
t(m) >= colMeans(m)
#       Y1    Y2   Z1   Z2   Z3
# A1 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# A2 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# B1 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
# B2 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

- With `t(t(m) >= colMeans(m))`, we transpose the result; now we have a logical matrix indicating whether each element in `m` exceeds its column mean:

```
t(t(m) >= colMeans(m))
#       A1    A2    B1    B2
# Y1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# Y2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# Z1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# Z2  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# Z3  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

- Finally `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` will return the row and column numbers that are set:

```
which(t(t(m) >= colMeans(m)), arr.ind=TRUE)
#    row col
# Z1   3   1
# Z2   4   1
# Z3   5   1
# Z1   3   2
# Z2   4   2
# Z3   5   2
# Z1   3   3
# Z2   4   3
# Z3   5   3
# Z1   3   4
# Z2   4   4
# Z3   5   4
```

All that remains is converting the column and row numbers to their associated names, which we do in the next two lines of code with simple indexing.